# Rbindlist error due to string to date conversion in a loop

Tags: r, date, lapply, mapply, rbindlist

I'm building a complex code that loops over 10-1000 files, and calculates a whole bunch of summary statistics for each file based on 6 grouping columns. That all works fine, but in the double apply structure, I'm also trying to extract the date from the filename and convert that to a date format, and add it as column to each data frame.

Without the date conversion in my full code, as well as in this example code it works fine, but with the conversion in it, it seems to cause the loop to suddenly produce strange errors.

I have tried dozen of ways to make it work. Normally single string to date format is not a problem for me, but how do I make this work in this loop structure?

At first I thought that the problem was that the date format conversion didn't work, but it seems to work, but it causes problems with the rbindlist code.

```
Error in rbindlist(ClusterResultlist[[cl]]) : 
  Column 2 of item 1 is length 11, inconsistent with first column of that item which is length 10. rbind/rbindlist doesn't recycle as it already expects each item to be a uniform list, data.frame or data.table
```

I have no clue why it's claiming that there is a difference in length, or how to solve it.

**Question: How to convert the strings to Date format either inside the loops, or afterwards.**

**my code:**

```
myfiles <- list("PICO in situ 55 10 100 100 100 2016-05-06 19u03_clustered_newtest1.csv", "PICO in situ 55 10 100 100 100 2016-05-07 19u03_clustered_newtest1.csv")

## list of clustering columns to summarize over
Clusterlist <- c('Cluster_FP1', 'Cl_names_FP1', 'GR_names_FP1', 'Cluster_FP2', 'Cl_names_FP2', 'GR_names_FP2') # 
ClusterResultlist <- vector("list", length(Clusterlist))
names(ClusterResultlist) <- Clusterlist

SummarizeData <- function(y){
  lapply(Clusterlist, function(z) { 
    datetime <- substr(y, nchar(y) -38, nchar(y) -23)
    FullCounts <- data.frame(DummyIndex = 1:10)
    FullCounts$DateTime <- strptime(datetime,format = "%Y-%m-%d %Hu%M")
    ClusterResultlist[[z]][[y]] <<- FullCounts
})}

# run the function over all files
mapply(SummarizeData, y = myfiles)

# create 6 main dataframes out of all sub data frames
lapply(Clusterlist, function(cl) { ClusterResultlist[[cl]] <<- rbindlist(ClusterResultlist[[cl]])  })
```

**UPDATE:** 
We have two (partial) solutions now, but they will not be as fast as rbindlist I believe on my actual large data object.

I tried to do the conversion outside the loops on the final ClusterResultList but that throws this error:

```
lapply(Clusterlist, function(cl) { ClusterResultlist[[cl]] <<- rbindlist(ClusterResultlist[[cl]])  })

lapply(Clusterlist, function(cl) { ClusterResultlist[[cl]]$DateTime <<- strptime(ClusterResultlist[[cl]]$DateTime,format = "%Y-%m-%d %Hu%M") })  



 In `[<-.data.table`(x, j = name, value = value) :
  Supplied 11 items to be assigned to 20 items of column 'DateTime' (recycled leaving remainder of 9 items).
```

Comment: P.S. this is a repost of an earlier question I wrote that had errors in it and was not simplified enough. Now the question is without the data frame part on summary statistics as I found out that that part was unrelated to the problem I encountered

Comment: I tried using `rbind.fill()` from `plyr` and it gave me a time zone error. I went back into the `strptime` call and added `tz = "GMT` and that did the trick for `rbind.fill()`, but didn't solve it for `rbindlist()`.

Comment: I guess it's a structural problem with the way rbindlist works. 
Would there be a way to do the time conversion on the list AFTER the mapply?

Comment: Using lubridate in the SummarizeData function seems to work out. `FullCounts$DateTime <- lubridate::ymd_hms(strptime(datetime,format = "%Y-%m-%d %Hu%M"))`

Comment: if you post it as an answer, I will give you the victory point csgroen! very nice fix!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixing the date with the help of `lubridate` fixes the problem with `rblindlist`.

Replace:

```
FullCounts$DateTime <- strptime(datetime,format = "%Y-%m-%d %Hu%M")
```

With:

```
FullCounts$DateTime <- lubridate::ymd_hms(strptime(datetime,format = "%Y-%m-%d %Hu%M"))
```

Answer (score 1):

How about using `rbind` instead of `rbindlist`?

```r
lapply(Clusterlist, function(cl) ClusterResultlist[[cl]] <<- do.call(rbind, ClusterResultlist[[cl]]))
```

Comment: hm yes that does the trick indeed. But will be much slower on my massive data structure I believe, hence the rbindlist, and I would like to understand why the problem occurs actually

Comment: If you replace `strptime` with `as.POSIXct` then also `rbindlist` works. So I am really not able to understand the reason behind the error which you are getting. BTW nice part is that you got your desired solution. Cheers!